# How do you set an active state on one component at a time, and remove the active state on all others in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a basic application, where I click on a dot and it changes the colour to red. I have two dots. However, I want to be able to click on one, give it its active state, then disable the active state on the other dot. Currently, I have it working. However, I don't feel confident its the right approach.

I've tried using this.setState to update the active states. But, I'm not getting anywhere with that

```
handleDot = id => {
    var state = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.dots.length; i++) {
      if (i === id) {
        state.dots[i].isActive = true;
      } else {
        state.dots[i].isActive = false;
      }
    }
    this.setState(state);
  };
```

The code I have is currently working, however, I'm looking for a possible better solution

Here is a link to my project

https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-grothendieck-1q319

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Object.assign({}, this.state)` you're performing a `shallow copy`, state's object's reference changes but the `dots` array continues the same. So what you're doing is mutating the current state.

`map` over the array and change to `true` the object that contains the selected `id` and false the others

```
handleDot = id =>{
    this.setState(prevState =>({
        dots: prevState.dots.map(dot => ({...dot, isActive: dot.id === id})) 
    }))
}
```

Using the `index`

```
handleDot = id =>{
    this.setState(prevState =>({
        dots: prevState.dots.map((dot,i) => ({...dot, isActive: i === id})) 
    }))
}
```

Now you're using the `updater` version of `setState` to `map` over the previous state's `dots` and returning a new array with the updated objects.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is get a refrence to dots and with querySelector all and run a for loop on them like this put this function above where you are setting class to active it will first remove all active class then you will add active class to the element you clicked hope it will help you

```
removeClass=()=>{
  var buttonArray = document.querySelectorAll('allDots');
  for (let i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) {
      const element = buttonArray[i];
      if (element.classList.contains('btn-active')) {
        element.classList.remove('btn-active')
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: and you dont need to use state for this